# Download a PDF via Ajax and Open in a New Browser Tab

Tags: javascript, html

I need to download a pdf via ajax request then open it in a new tab. I know that major browsers discourage this but is this possible?

I currently use window.open then execute the pdf download in the new window.

Comment: You could create an <a download> tag and execute it after window.open has been invoked. As of those, a new window would open and the download will be performed.

Comment: You want the browser to automatically access the users personal filesystem at a certain time, and open an arbitrary file in a new browser tab? Because that doesn't sound like something a browser should let happen. The user will need to allow this to happen or it suddenly becomes a shady practice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `window.open` and `target="_blank`" is that most browsers will block this as a popup. `target="_self"` works fine though but is not the desired behaviour